# Intergation testing with play 2.5.4 and DI - play configuration won't load

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, integration-testing, playframework-2.5

I want to integration test an app by spinning up an in memory database. I had thought this might not be too tricky with the dependency injection:

```
class TreatySpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with Results {

  val testConf = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("test.conf"))

  override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.Test).loadConfig(testConf).bindings(new TestModule()).build()

  "Routes" should {

    "404 on a bad request" in {
      route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/boum")).map(status(_)) mustBe Some(NOT_FOUND)
    }

  }
}
```

When executed, I get the following error:

```
[info] TreatySpec:
[info] Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: TreatySpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'slick.dbs.h2'
```

Here is my `test.conf`:

```
slick.dbs.h2.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.h2.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.h2.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test"
slick.dbs.h2.db.username=""
slick.dbs.h2.db.password=""

slick.dbs.h2 {

  driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
  db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
  db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:spotRepo"
  db.username=""
  db.password=""

}

slick.dbs{

  h2.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
  h2.driver="org.h2.Driver"
  h2.url="jdbc:h2:mem:spotRepo"
  h2.username=""
  h2.password=""
}
```

I thought the Guice module was supposed to load the configuration? Whatever I do, there doesn't appear to be the relevant key in the config.

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    override def configure() = {
        // Use the system clock as the default implementation of Clock
        bind(classOf[Clock]).toInstance(Clock.systemDefaultZone)
    }

    val dbConfigString = "slick.dbs.h2"

    @Provides
    val dbConfig  : DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile](dbConfigString)
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? What am I doing wrong such that play refuses to load the configuration?

Comment: I remember once having had such issues and the problem ended up being a wrongly set classloader. Maybe this helps: https://gist.github.com/rethab/01fde763d10f29273d43

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave this a go, but it looks like something is fundamentally different in play 2.5.4 ... as the linked class gives me compiles errors. It could simply be that I don't understand the magic which is taking place...

Comment: You may try to put your test config in `test/resources/application.conf`. It should be automatically loaded and merged with the regular `conf/application.conf`

Comment: Wow, this got me past one hurdle. Thanks... however, it appears that play then doesn't apply evolution if I configure the test application.conf to use an H2 database. Would it be expected too? It does appear to do it on a normal startup though ...